# 2Checkout payment using Korean Won currency

Tags: php, html, paypal, payment-gateway, 2checkout

I want to integrate 2checkout payment gateway with my website. I have opened a sandbox account. I made a HTML page like bellow and it is working:

```
<form action='https://sandbox.2checkout.com/checkout/purchase' method='post'>
<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='901249407'>
<input type='hidden' name='quantity' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='USD'>
<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Buy from 2CO' >
</form>
```

I need to pay in Korean Won in my website. So I set the currency_code to KRW which is supported according to this doc:
https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/payment-api/create-sale

But it is giving an **Internal Server Error**.

[image: Internal Server Error]

Can you guys suggest me how to add korean currency support? and why is the error occuring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KRW is currently not available to test in our sandbox environment, I responded to your internal ticket with us so please review that information as it provides a workaround.